# Unresolved reference: Color

Tags: kotlin

Why did this error happen?
It's very simple code.
Should I use capital letters?

```
fun getMnemonic(color: Color) = when (color) {   

    color.RED -> "Richard"   
    color.ORANGE -> "Of" 
    color.YELLOW -> "York" 
    color.GREEN -> "Gave" 
    color.BLUE -> "Battle" 
    color.INDIGO -> "In" 
    color.VIOLET -> "Vain" 
    else -> println("ok retry") 
}    

fun main() {
    println(getMnemonic(color.BLUE))
}
```

Error message is:
Unresolved reference: Color

Comment: what `Color` class are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Apparently if you type out Color.RED instead of selecting it from the auto-complete dropdown, the import doesn't kick in automatically.

You got to import :

```
import android.graphics.Color
```

Answer (score -2):

It appears to be saying the type "Color" isn't defined